# How can I update the expires property on createdAt field in mongoose to avoid the document being deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to add account verification to this app and I have set a user account that has been created but not verified to delete itself after 30 seconds using.

```
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
  index: {
    expires: 30,
  },
},
```

But now I am looking for a way to prevent the document from being deleted after 30 seconds but I haven't found a working solution.

Comment: instead of deleting the user account, isn't the best approach will be maintain a status and mark it as 'notVerified' ?

Comment: We don't want the data taking up space so we want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

Let's say this is `User` model.

```js
await User.syncIndexes();
```

The other thing you will need to update in `User` model is:

```js
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose uses MongoDB TTL indexes to expire documents, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

> If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.
>
> If a document does not contain the indexed field, the document will not expire.

So to prevent the document expiring you might unset the field, set it to a non-date value, or set the date into the far future.